# Animate ball JPanel subclass is not abstract error

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel, abstraction

I have made a simple shape program that animates a ball within a `JPanel`. My public class shape is flagging an error saying shape is not abstract (see screenshot below)

> Shape is not abstract and does not override abstract method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in `ActionListener`

[Abstract error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKTwv.png)

Shape.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

 public class Shape extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double velX = 2;
    double velY = 2;

   public void painComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40);

       g2.fill(circle);
       t.start(); 
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if (x < 0 || x > 560) {
           velX = -velX;
       }

       if(y < 0 || y > 360) {
           velY = -velY;
       }

       x += velX;
       y += velY;
       repaint();
   }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = new Shape();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.add(s);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Moving Ball");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note incorrect spelling of `paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

You probably want this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

In your implementation of `paintComponent()` and `actionPerformed()`, use [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html), which "informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass." The compiler can then help you identify spelling and type errors.

```
public class Shape extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    …
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {…}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {…}
}
```

You can override `getPreferredSize()` to reflect your chosen geometry. Also, consider refactoring the numeric constants.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(560, 360);
}
```

[image]